# How to generate session id and auth bearer token for a payment sandbox http request and it is not available in any of the previous request

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, payment-gateway, braintree-sandbox

There is a ecommerce application in which I have to add product and make payment for checkout. Payment mode is sandbox for now.
So, Payment.sandbox.api http request url is having session id in the payload and auth bearer token in http request header, but these are not available in any of the previous response ,so that I can fetch it from the response but that is not available

So further it is giving me authentication issue,that credentials are invalid, that may be because of session id and auth token. So how to handle them or how to populate them automatically as I am not getting in any of the previous request?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [BrainTree Documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/overview) there are 2 ways of authenticating the client:

1. [Tokenization Keys](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/tokenization-key/javascript/v3) - can be obtained from [production or sandbox control panel](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/tokenization-key/javascript/v3#obtaining-a-tokenization-key)
2. [Client Token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/client-token) - you need to [replicate client authentication flow](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3#get-a-client-token), JMeter is Java-based application so I believe the easiest would be using [Braintree Java SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/java) from the [JSR223 Preprocessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)